# You have specified an invalid database connection group (source) in your config/database.php file

Tags: php, sql-server, database, codeigniter, crud

i'm getting this error.

> You have specified an invalid database connection group (source) in your config/database.php file.

the code already read the database but there is an error above
What is the problem?
**database.config** - database config

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;


$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=FMM-PROEXC12\SQLEXPRESS04;Database=db_fmm;',
    'hostname' => 'FMM-PROEXC12\SQLEXPRESS04',
    'username' => 'loginDB',
    'password' => 'Poiuy123',
    'database' => 'db_fmm',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',   
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

**M_data.php** -data model

```
<?php

class M_data extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()

    {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->database();

    }
    function ambil_data()
    {

        return $this->db->get('users');
    }
}
```

**login.php** -controller

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('M_login');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('V_login');
    }

    function aksi_login()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $where = array(
            'username' => $username,    
            'password' => $password
        );
        // $cek = $this->M_login->cek_login("users", $where)->num_row();
        $query = $this->db->query("select COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", array($username, $password));
        $result = $query->row();

        $cek = $result->count;

        if ($cek > 0) {

            $data_session = array(
                'nama' => $username,
                'status' => "login"
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
            redirect(("dasboard"));
        } else {
            echo "Username dan password salah !";
        }
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(('login'));
    }
}
```

**M_login.php** -login model

```
<?php

class M_login extends CI_Model
{
    function cek_login($table, $where)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($table, $where);
    }
}
```